# Can new domains be added to existing OAuth app?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have developed and deployed an app that requires `OAuth` (Google, Microsoft) to sign in. Due to some reasons, I now want to change my domain. I have the following questions

- If I change to new domain, do I need to create new client id and secret?
- If I change the Redirect URL to point to new domain, will the existing users who have already given permission for this app to read/write emails need to authorize again?

This question is applicable to both Google and Microsoft OAuth client id.